# How to trace a wire hidden behind plywood wall?

Tags: wire, electricity, wire-terminals

I have multiple electrical lines running behind my plywood wall. Unfortunately, some wires got lost behind the wall and the electrician is unable to trace them. Now the wire which I want to trace has its one end in sight. I want to find the other end. Many other wires may criss-cross this wire inside the wall which doesn't concern me. Is there a simple way to find the other end? There are some detectors available in the market which cost many thousand rupees. I want to avoid purchasing them.

Comment: maybe you may be able to rent detection equipment

Comment: consider drilling a hole for an endoscope (maybe $15 and useful for other things) or just pull the plywood sheet down and be done with it. Refinishing is not that hard.

Comment: Get cable tracing equipment eg: Fluke 2042

Answer (score 1):

Do this with POWER TURNED OFF.

Use a 74HC14 Schmitt Trigger IC, in a self_oscillating R+C feedback.

The edge speed will be plenty fast to produce numerous responses in an AM radio, if you have a 50,000 Hertz oscillation frequency. Approximately, not crucial.
And the 5 volts operation also helps.

Pick one of the 6 available Inverters.

For that inverter, connect 1Kohm, or 1.2Kohm, or 1.5Kohm, or 1.8Kohm or 2.2Kohm from output to input.

Select a small capacitor to use on the inverter_input pin.

For 50,000 Hertz (20 microsecond period), you need about 10 microseconds time constant. Since varying the VDD will change the frequency, you need not be precise. A cap of 0.01uF from Inverter input_pin to Ground will, with 1Kohm, produce ( R times C ) 0.01uF * 1Kohm = 1e-8 * 1e+3 = 1e-5 = 10 uSec TAU.

To provide VDD (approximately +5v), use a 6 volt battery with 1N4001 or 1N4148 in series.

Have 0.1 or 0.01 uF cap across the VDD and GND pins: pin 14 and pin 7.

Have a small cap from inverter output to a wire with alligator clip, that attaches to the wire.

Notice there is NO RETURN path.

And you must have POWER TURNED OFF.

Answer (score 0):

My simple detector is as follows: A small XTAL oscilator battery powered is attached to wires, on their ends a resistor is connected acting as a load. With a AM radio (I have SSB pocket AM recever) serach for a wire.

Similar xtal transmitter:

[image]

Comment: With no component values that's not going to be very useful to a novice asker.  Also they probably don't have a receiver with a BFO so would not get a tone.